# copy_to_user returns an error in a char device read function

Tags: c, linux-kernel, mips, embedded-linux

I've implemented a char device for my kernel module and implemented a read function for it. The read function calls `copy_to_user` to return data to the caller. I've originally implemented the read function in a blocking manner (with `wait_event_interruptible`) but the problem reproduces even when I implement read in a non-blocking manner. My code is running on a MIPS procesor.

The user space program opens the char device and reads into a buffer allocated on the stack.

What I've found is that occasionally `copy_to_user` will fail to copy any bytes. Moreover, even if I replace `copy_to_user` with a call to `memcpy` (only for the purposes of checking... I know this isn't the right thing to do), and print out the destination buffer immediately afterwards, I see that `memcpy` has failed to copy any bytes.

I'm not really sure how to further debug this - how can I determine why memory is not being copied? Is it possible that the process context is wrong?

**EDIT**: Here's some pseudo-code outlining what the code currently looks like:

User mode (runs repeatedly):

```
char buf[BUF_LEN];
FILE *f = fopen(char_device_file, "rb");
fread(buf, 1, BUF_LEN, f);
fclose(f);
```

Kernel mode:

```
char_device = 
    create_char_device(char_device_name,
        NULL,
        read_func,
        NULL,
        NULL);

int read_func(char *output_buffer, int output_buffer_length, loff_t *offset)
{
    int rc;
    if (*offset == 0)
    {
        spin_lock_irqsave(&lock, flags);

        while (get_available_bytes_to_read() == 0)
        {
            spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock, flags);
            if (wait_event_interruptible(self->wait_queue, get_available_bytes_to_read() != 0))
            {
                // Got a signal; retry the read
                return -ERESTARTSYS;
            }

            spin_lock_irqsave(&lock, flags);
        }

        rc = copy_to_user(output_buffer, internal_buffer, bytes_to_copy);

        spin_unlock_irqrestore(&lock, flags);
    } 
    else rc = 0;

    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Something wrong with your code, but you don't show it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Added some pseudo-code, hopefully it illustrates enough of what's being done by the code. Unfortunately I haven't (yet) been able to narrow it down to a small, reproducing example.

Comment: @YSK You have declared `int rc` two times. Remove `int` from the line `int rc = copy_to_user(output_buffer, internal_buffer, bytes_to_copy);`.

Comment: As any other "may-block" function, `copy_to_user` shouldn't be called with spinlock taken.

Comment: @Gaurav good point - unfortunately I don't have a pseudo-code compiler :)

Comment: @Tsyvarev that's great feedback. Can you say what the impact would be of calling `copy_to_user` under a spinlock? Can paged memory (that the OS can't page in while the spinlock is taken?) explain what I'm observing?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Also, I'm not quite sure how to call `copy_to_user` not under spinlock. The problem is that the "producer" that's filling data into my internal buffer is a netfilter hook which AFAIK can be called from interrupt context, which means I have to use a spinlock there. Does this mean I need a background "process" which will copy data from a spinlock-protected buffer to a semaphore-protected buffer, and then my char device read function will read from the semaphore-protected buffer?

Comment: `that the OS can't page in while the spinlock is taken?` - Exactly. If the page is not loaded, OS cannot load it while under spinlock. `The problem is that the "producer" that's filling data into my internal buffer is a netfilter hook which AFAIK can be called from interrupt context, which means I have to use a spinlock there.` - There are several lock-free approaches for producer-consumer interaction. E.g., [circular buffer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/circular-buffers.txt).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'll give circular buffer a read (we've actually implemented something similar ourselves, but it's protected by a spinlock). Not sure if it matters, but our current (embedded) system has no swap memory at all. Can `copy-to-user` still block in such scenarios? Is it still a bad idea to use it under a spinlock? And additionally, can the use of `copy_to_user` under a spinlock explain the symptoms we're seeing (`copy-to-user` fails to copy any data)? I'd have expected a kernel panic or something.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know whether `copy_to_user` can be used  under spinlock in your specific case. I just know that *in general* such usage is forbidden. As for symptoms... they don't look like `copy_to_user` attempts to block under spinlock (it would be some sort of crash). Probably, value of `bytes_to_copy` is incorrect, or similar.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you. I'll do my homework re. the circular buffer. Can you suggest troubleshooting steps for what causes `copy_to_user` to fail? I know that memory access is one possible cause, but the fact that the failures are sporadic makes me suspect that memory access is not the problem (I always use a stack-based buffer). Am I doing something wrong with the blocking IO? Is it possible that when IO is ready to be copied, I'm running in the wrong process context?

Comment: Why do you talk about wrong process context? `wait_event_interruptible` returns to the process context from which it was called.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I was trying to come up with a way to understand why `copy_to_user` would fail. Other than access checks (which I think should succeed given that I always use stack-based memory), I wasn't sure what else could cause a copy failure. BTW, I have now removed the blocking logic - i.e. `read_func` now just copies the data under the spinlock - and so far I am unable to reproduce the failure, which indicates that perhaps something is indeed wrong with the way I block.

Comment: @Tsyvarev seems it may have been the spinlock after all - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took quite a bit of debugging, but in the end Tsyvarev's hint (the comment about not calling `copy_to_user` with a spinlock taken) seems to have been the cause.

Our process had a background thread which occasionally launched a new process (`fork` + `exec`). When we disabled this thread, everything worked well. The best theory we have is that the fork made all of our memory pages copy-on-write, so when we tried to copy to them, the kernel had to do some work which could not be done with the spinlock taken. Hopefully it at least makes some sense (although I'd have guessed that this would apply only to the child process, and the parent's process pages would simply remain writable, but who knows...).

We rewrote our code to be lockless and the problem disappeared.

Now we just need to verify that our lockless code is indeed safe on different architectures. Easy as pie.

Comment: I encounter a problem with the program that have similar scenario with yours, i.e. one thread use fork() + exec() to launch new process, and another thread read device input with copy_to_user() and spinlock() in kernel. But what I can confirm is that occasional crash with SIGSEGV in new-launched process. I wonder whether we have the same root cause.

Comment: @gzh possibly... I never did fully understand why `copy_to_user` failed, but it did. But do you understand why you got a `SIGSEGV`? Can a `copy_to_user` failure explain this for your app? I think the next troubleshooting step for you should be to get a core dump and analyze it. But regardless - calling `copy_to_user` under a spinlock seems like a bad idea...

Comment: I have gotten the coredump of subprocess, but I can not find any evidence that can incur a SIGSEGV from coredump. The si_addr is  lower address such as 0xf, is far from those processing shown by backtrace. And I can confirm from coredump that subprocess dead in ld-linux.so when loading dependent libraries. I also noticed that some times read syscall will return negative value other than -1.

Comment: @gzh ah - the joy of core dumps... what platform are you running on? x86 or something else? Any chance it's your kernel code that mucks up the process' memory?

Comment: I use ARM platform. There is only one thread in subprecess. The only possibility to incur SIGSEGV I can imagine is the driver module in kernel, Or corrupted memory by inherited file descriptor when running fork().

Comment: @gzh perhaps post a new question with more details about the crash you're having?

Comment: OK, I created a new question and posted the coredump result. Thanks.